Unable to populate data in XREF in SOA BPEL 12c
I am trying to do a simple implmentation of XREF in SOA BPEL 12c. I have created an XREF with end system as tokenType, Token and UpdatedOn.

Used populateXRefRow to populated values in XREF.

xref:populateXRefRow('MyXref.xref','tokenType','EBS100',
'Token','CM001SDFSD34','ADD')

While running the BPEL I get below error:

XPath expression failed to execute. An error occurs while processing
the XPath expression; the expression is
xref:populateXRefRow('MyXref.xref','tokenType','EBS100',
'Token','CM001','ADD') The XPath expression failed to execute; the
reason was: oracle.fabric.common.xml.xpath.XPathFunctionException:
Invalid metadata for Cross Reference Table "MyXref.xref" Please ensure
the metadata confirms to the XSD. Check the detailed root cause
described in the exception message text and verify that the XPath
query is correct.


Found the issue. My XREF file was inside 'XREFs' folder. So populateXRefRow should be like this.
xref:populateXRefRow('XREFs/MyXref.xref','tokenType','EBS100', 'Token','CM001SDFSD34','ADD')

